# TabView Interfering with Startup Screen Header Height

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have a tab view within a navigation view. At startup, ContentView() sets up the tab views followed by StartUpView().

When StartUpView() is called by itself, it contains the blue reserved block at the top of the view plus a small block below that contains two buttons (one to a menu and a save button for future logic below).

When I run StartupView() from ContentView() the blue block is more than twice the size (33 mm) as when StartupView() is called directly by itself (15 mm).

Within StartUpView() I have to increase the GeometryReader percentage from 60% to 80% in order to display the two buttons. Is there any way to maintain the original height of the blue block?

What I am aiming for--This is the view when running StartupView() by itself https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kCvM.png

This is what the StartupView() looks like when called from the tab view logic.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bve7p.png

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tabs = .home

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            TabView (selection: $selectedTab) {
                StartUpView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Tab A", systemImage: "a.circle.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.taba)

                TabBView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Tab B", systemImage: "b.circle.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.tabb)

                TabCView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Tab C", systemImage: "c.circle.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.tabc)

                TabDView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Tab D", systemImage: "d.circle.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.tabd)

                TabEView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Tab E", systemImage: "e.circle.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.tabe)
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}


 struct StartupView: View {
 
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { g in
                ZStack (alignment: .top) {
                    Color.blue
                        .frame(height: (g.safeAreaInsets.top) * 0.6, alignment: .top)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()

                        .navigationTitle("Title")

                        .toolbar {
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                                NavigationLink (destination: SettingsView()) {
                                    Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                                }
                            }

                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                Button(action: {
                                    print("save tapped!")
                                }){
                                    Text("Save")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)

                                }
                            }
                        }
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try removing the geometry reader from StartupView()

Comment: The `TabView` only works properly at the upper most level. You can have a `NavigationView` in each tab. remove the upper most `NavigationView`

Comment: Thanks @lorem ipsum: I have been placing the NavigationView at the top of my tab selector. This appears to work better with the startup view and also doesn't fall out of views upon change in orientation.

Comment: @kishore chandru: I need geometry reader since it sets the height of the blue block at the top of the view. The height varies with the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need second `NavigationView` inside `StartUpView` - there should be only one in hierarchy. And the issue is due to this second navigation view navigation bar.

So a fixed part is

```
 struct StartUpView: View {

    var body: some View {
//        NavigationView {          // << removed !!
        GeometryReader { g in
           // ... other code
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5